# How to maintain session in Facebook messenger bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to store quick replies of my bot in the express session of my application but unfortunately, it didn't work. Below is my code

```
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
server.get("/", (req, res) => f.registerHook(req, res));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(cookieParser());
server.use(session({secret: "Shh, its a secret!"}));

//my webhook which registered in the app
server.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.ii) {
    req.session.ii+=req.session.ii
  } 
else req.session.ii=1;
})
```

But when I hit the webhook manually(from postman)it works.when it is being called by facebook internally then session is not retaining. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: _What_ session? You are aware that these requests are not made by your app _users_ resp. their client devices, but that Facebook makes them in the background … right?

Comment: @CBroe ya that's correct. here my requirement is I want to store quick replies in some object like session so that I won't send it again which already sent. I can do this with help DB which is an extra burden for me

Comment: Well you won’t get any cookies here from the request that Facebook sends. At most, you could specify a _fixed_ session id yourself in your code, so that it picks up the _same_ session all the time. (Whether that is as easily possible in Node, as it would be f.e. in PHP, I can’t tell you.) But that would rather be an abuse of the session mechanism to begin with IMHO.